# How to change the quantity of the product if removed in PHP?

Tags: php, html, jquery, session

I have a form where I am inserting personal data and images. The user can add more than one image. Now when the user submits the form then I am inserting the data and images in the temporary table and creating a session for images that are as below.

```
$_SESSION['workimages']=$storeWorkImages;
```

I am getting the output which is correct (For example user added 3 images).

```
Array ( 
[0] => 1381658980.jpeg 
[1] => 211907337.png 
[2] => 266964890.jpg 
)
```

Till now, the User data in a temporary table. I don't have any issues here.

Now what I am doing is, I am displaying all the images on the checkout page where the user can view the images for confirmation. So I use the below code.

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['workimages'])){?>
<form method="post" id="checkout" name="checkout" action="#" autocomplete="off">
  <?php  foreach($_SESSION['workimages'] as $workimages){?>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="assets/images/uploads/<?php echo $workimages;?>" alt="" class="workimg">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="disabledme btn_workremove">Remove</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="disabledme btn_workrestore">Restore</a>
    </li>
    <?php }?>
  </ul>
  <div class="calculateWrap">
    <label>quantity</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo count($_SESSION['workimages']);?>" name="qty" id="qty">
    <label>Amount</label> $
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="totalamt" value="1">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="1"> <!--1 is for testing-->
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed to pay">
</form>
<?php }?>
```

I am using the below script for `remove` and `restore`.

(Note: The below script is used only for adding the class and display the remove and restore the text. It is not completely removing from the session.)

I don't want to remove from the session because the user can reactive the image again.

```
$(function() {   
  $(".btn_workremove").click(function() {  
    $(this).parent().addClass("disabledimage");  
     $('.disabledimage .btn_workrestore').addClass("d-block"); 
  });
  
  $(".btn_workrestore").click(function() {  
    $(this).parent().removeClass("disabledimage"); 
    $(this).removeClass("d-block"); 
    $('.disabledimage .btn_workremove').addClass("d-block"); 
  });

});
```

Check the below image. I am getting this output.

(Note: The second image removed but still I want to show it to the user.)

[image]

Now if I click on `Proceed to pay button` then I am inserting the all the data in the real table (I am sharing only checkout query here).

```
$qty = validate_data($_POST['qty']);
$amount = validate_data($_POST['amount']);
$user_id = validate_data($_POST['user_id']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_checkout`(`qty`, `amount`, `user_id`) VALUES (:qty, :amount, :user_id)";
$stmt = $pdo - > prepare($sql);
$stmt - > execute(['qty' => $qty,
  'amount' => $amount,
  'user_id' => $user_id
]);
```

Now my main issue is, I am getting 3 qty instead of 2. I removed second image but still giving me 3 qty.

What can I try next?

Comment: Add the "disabled" attribute to the input when you click remove, disabled inputs are not send with POST.

Comment: @PeterSH, Yes, disabled will not send to the POST but where I have to use that disabled? I am directing taking the qty value. Where I have to change it?

Comment: The disabled attribute is an input atttribute, you can find more info here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: @PeterSH, Yes, but where should I use that. If I use in the qty then how can I get the value of qty in the checkout page?

Comment: You are getting the quantity by counting the images in the session, $_SESSION is a server variable and cannot be changed with javascript. I would suggest making the quantity a javascript variable and remove 1 when remove is clicked.

Comment: @PeterSH, Can you help me more hint? Or any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the quantity by counting the amount of images is the session variable

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo count($_SESSION['workimages']);?>" name="qty" id="qty">
```

The session variable is a server-side variable, you cannot change this with javascript. I would suggest using jQuery to remove or add 1 to the quantity when remove or restore is clicked.

example:

```
$(function() {
  $(".btn_workremove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("disabledimage");
    $('.disabledimage .btn_workrestore').addClass("d-block");
    var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val())
    $('#qty').val(qty - 1) // <---- remove 1 from quantity
  });

  $(".btn_workrestore").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("disabledimage");
    $(this).removeClass("d-block");
    $('.disabledimage .btn_workremove').addClass("d-block");
    var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val())
    $('#qty').val(qty + 1) // <---- add 1 to quantity
  });

});
```

Comment: Give me sometime to check